# as3 display webview below objects

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash

I was wondering if anybody knows a way or method to display on as3 a webview external html page to the back of a display abject?
here is my code

```
import flash.filesystem.FileMode;
import flash.filesystem.FileStream;
import flash.filesystem.File;

var fPath:String = "http://mysite.com/demo.php";

var webView = new StageWebView();
webView.stage = stage;
webView.viewPort = new Rectangle(15, 283, 340, 327);
webView.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);
webView.loadURL( fPath );

function onComplete(event:Event):void{
    trace("event = ", event);
    trace("event.target = ", event.target);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

StageWebView is always on top of the display list. There is a work around where you can draw it to BitmapData object and then display that in a Bitmap in the back of the display list using [drawViewPortToBitmapData](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/StageWebView.html#drawViewPortToBitmapData%28%29)

Obviously the drawn version is not interactive.

hth.

Comment: Thank you for the fast response, just what i was looking for!